# How to loop through subdirectories filled with images and assign a function to each images individually?

Tags: python

I am working on a face recognition system. I have a folder filled with subdirectories which has images inside it. I want to loop through these images located inside the subfolders and apply face_align function(which I have created) which is responsible for face cropping and alignment and save the aligned and cropped images in another folders that has the same architecture like before

For example: If I have : subdirectories called 'Thor','Loki' and 'Odin' with raw original pictures,I want to loop through these and apply the face_align function and automatically create another folder called aligned face which will have the same subdirectories 'Thor','Loki' and 'Odin'. but with aligned and cropped faces.

So far I have tried:

```
#Now that we have defined the face alignmet and cropping, we walk through each subfolder and use the align function
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('<path to subdirectories that has face pictures>'):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, fname)
        with open(fpath, 'rb') as f, open('<path to new folder>', 'w') as newfile:
            data = f.read()
            new_data = align_face(data) #Implementing align_face function 
            newfile.write(new_data)
```

It seems to however not work. It seems to run through the align_face function easily however, it doesn't copy those aligned images into new folder. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**This is the align face function**

```
def align_face(imagePath):

    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(imagePath)

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

    face_landmarks = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)

    if len(face_locations) == 0:
        print("Couldn't detect face for pid {} in path {}".format(Id,imagePath))

        return []

    if len(face_locations) > 1:
        return []

    else:
        (top, right, bottom, left) = face_locations[0]

        desiredWidth = (right - left)

        desiredHeight = (bottom - top)

        leftEyePts = face_landmarks[0]['left_eye']

        rightEyePts = face_landmarks[0]['right_eye']

        if len(leftEyePts) == 0 or len(rightEyePts) == 0:

            print("Couldn't detect both eyes for pid {} in path {}".format(Id,imagePath))
            return []


        else:

            leftEyeCenter = np.array(leftEyePts).mean(axis=0).astype("int")

            rightEyeCenter = np.array(rightEyePts).mean(axis=0).astype("int")

            leftEyeCenter = (leftEyeCenter[0],leftEyeCenter[1])

            rightEyeCenter = (rightEyeCenter[0],rightEyeCenter[1])

            dY = rightEyeCenter[1] - leftEyeCenter[1]

            dX = rightEyeCenter[0] - leftEyeCenter[0]
            
            angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(dY, dX))

            desiredLeftEye=(0.35, 0.35)

            desiredFaceWidth = desiredWidth

            desiredFaceHeight = desiredHeight

            desiredRightEyeX = 1.0 - desiredLeftEye[0]

            dist = np.sqrt((dX ** 2) + (dY ** 2))

            desiredDist = (desiredRightEyeX - desiredLeftEye[0])
            
            desiredDist *= desiredFaceWidth

            scale = desiredDist / dist
            
            eyesCenter = ((leftEyeCenter[0] + rightEyeCenter[0]) // 2,
                (leftEyeCenter[1] + rightEyeCenter[1]) // 2)

            M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(eyesCenter, angle, scale)
            
            tX = desiredFaceWidth * 0.5

            tY = desiredFaceHeight * desiredLeftEye[1]

            M[0, 2] += (tX - eyesCenter[0])

            M[1, 2] += (tY - eyesCenter[1])
            
            (w, h) = (desiredFaceWidth, desiredFaceHeight)

            output = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

            output = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            print("images aligned")
            
            return output
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

your_dir_path = '...' # String. The path of your directory containing all your subdirectories
new_dir_path = '...' # The path of your new directory with the same architecture as the previous one, but with cropped and aligned faces

for subfolder in next(os.walk(your_dir_path))[1] : # Gives the list of all subdirectories inside the parent directory
  os.makedirs(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder)) # Creates the new subdirectory. Note that it will also create new_dir_path, so there's no need to add a line os.makedirs(new_dir_path)
  for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(your_dir_path, subfolder)) : # Gives the list of all files inside the 'subfolder' directory
    
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(your_dir_path, subfolder, file))
    #img = np.asarray(img) # If your align_face function works with numpy arrays
    new_img = align_face(img)
    #new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(new_img)) # If your align_face function returns a numpy array
    new_img.save(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder, file))
```

If the folder already exists, `os.makedirs(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder))` will throw an error. In that case, you can either delete this line (if you already created your `new_dir_path` folder with all its architecture), or delete the existing folder before re-creating it :

```
from shutil import rmtree # deletes a folder
```

and insert this line in the previous code :

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder)) :
  rmtree(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder))

os.makedirs(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder))
...
```

Comment: Thanks but why am I getting error :FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists .It points the problem to this line of code os.makedirs(os.path.join(new_dir_path, subfolder))

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope it better fits you now

Comment: thank. you. I have managed to use. try and. exception to avoid it however, I keep getting this error ''JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).
In your case using glob and a regex you can find all images (assuming that the root dir is the current active directory), iterate through them and store the newly created image in the destination folder

```
import glob, os
from pathlib import Path

destination_dir_path = "bawfaw"
image_paths = glob.glob("*/*/*.jpg") #in case those are jpg images
for image_path in image_paths:
 destination_image_path = Path(os.path.join(destination_dir_path, image_path))
 destination_image_folder = destination_image_path.parent

 if os.path.exists(destination_image_folder) is False:
   destination_image_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
 with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
  # process the image as you want and store it at destination_image_path
```

Code is not tested but I think it gives the general idea.